# How can I forbid access to login file for bots

Tags: php

what is the best way to forbid access for bots to login file? I just don't want let them to login to website. Is it possible?

Comment: How could they login even if they wanted to?

Comment: Define what a "bot" is.

Comment: bot = php curl crawler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats why we have [Captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)  Sequences and Images   . Which eats our head whenever they appear.

Bots Basically use Brute Force algorithms to get access into your site.

So you can stop any bot from using brute force by applying this captcha if any session has two wrong password attempts.

Create Sessions for each login using PHP and show that captcha whenever there are two wrong password attempts.

Comment: It will be very annoying for the users if they have to fill captcha every time they will be logging in

Comment: Not every time .... basicallly Bots try to use Brute Force to crack in passwords.... Use the captcha whenever the user enters wrong password twice.... Even Google Does that...

Comment: but I thought bots who will know their nick and password, so they will not have a problem with login

Comment: Those are not BOTs.... Bots are Programs that run to crack passwords and access the sites...

Well it is impossible to actually forbid someone/ bot to not acces if it/him/her know the real username and password.

Comment: I made a test today on 1 site. I have successfully logged in but after when I opened some other page it shows me error(in a console) that I don't have access to this website because my curl bot is not on their's domain or subdomain, or something like that

Comment: If anyone knows your password and username.... God also cannot forbid you from the attack... :(

Comment: @dont You cannot distinguish between HTTP requests originated "by a person" from HTTP requests originated from "a bot" without throwing something like a captcha their way. What are you actually afraid of?